# Was Tywin Lannister involved in the murder plot?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, game-of-thrones

Throughout *Game of Thrones* it's implied that Olenna Tyrell and Petyr Baelish were involved in Joffrey's murder and they pulled this off with the help of Sansa and Ser Dontos of House Hollard.

But could his grandfather and the Hand of the King be possibly involved with his murder?

Take a look at the fact that Joffrey acted weirdly three times with Tywin Lannister and that made him seriously angry.

As soon as he died he started giving life lessons to Tommen, and he was okay with killing children as he gave the order to kill infants of Rheagar and Elia Martell, and just before the Wedding Lady Olenna and Tywin had a little chat.

Comment: By that logic he hurt tyrion also and many other people

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Tywin Lannister had no hand in the murder of his grandson Joffrey.  Rather than explain how the murder occurred (detailed very well by Paulie_D's answer), I'll analyze Tywin and why he didn't, or couldn't, have done it.

Tywin, at the end of the day, is both a power player and a family man.  Almost everything Tywin does is for the sake of either boosting his own power or the name of his family, usually by putting his three kids in places of influence and power.  Cersei, as queen.  Jaime, as a member of the King's guard, and Tyrion, as Hand of the King (and over various roles over time).

Yes, Joffrey openly defied Tywin on several occasions, but Tywin is the kind of person that plays the long game and will use a person's interests to further his own interests.

After Joffrey's murder, Tywin was already wheeling and dealing to get Tyrion out of the situation as best he could.  Tyrion, his most hated son, was still important to him.  If Tywin was still willing to work with Tyrion, he surely had enough patience to cultivate Joffrey into, if not a GREAT leader, at least a less murderous one.

Comment: Tywin dealt with Tyrion by giving him a harsh lesson in his teens, at the appropriate time - Joffrey is still pretty young as well, so hasn't learned consequence. If Tywin was to do anything to Joffrey, it seems like harsh lesson would be a step he would take before murder.

Comment: Tywin did not put Jaime in the Kings Guard, The Mad King asked this of him so that Jaime had to renounce all claims to title's, land and marriage in the future. It was a political move on Tywin

Comment: I'd say, more, that Joffrey ***tried*** to defy Tywin.  In the end, he still got sent to his room, in the most prominent example I can think of. Minor quibble.

Answer (score 9):

**No** the culprit was....

## Olenna Redwyne Tyrell, aka the Queen of Thorns

At least, **so far**...according to George R.R. Martin<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1 - Now confirmed as per Season 7 Episode 3</sup>

[**RollingStone.com**](http://www.rollingstone.com/tv/news/george-r-r-martin-on-who-killed-joffrey-20140414)

> Martin: In the books — and I make no promises, because I have two more books to write, and I may have more surprises to reveal — the conclusion that the careful reader draws is that **Joffrey was killed by the Queen of Thorns**, using poison from Sansa’s hair net, so that if anyone actually did think it was poison, then Sansa would be blamed for it. Sansa had certainly good reason for it.
>
> The reason I bring this up is because I think that’s an interesting question of redemption. That’s more like killing Hitler. Does the Queen of Thorns need redemption? Did the Queen of Thorns kill Hitler, or did she murder a 13-year-old boy? Or both? She certainly had good reasons to remove Joffrey. Everything she’d heard about him, he was wildly unstable, and he was about to marry her beloved granddaughter. **The Queen of Thorns had studied Joffrey well enough that she knew that at some point he would get bored with Margaery, and Margaery would be maltreated**, the same way that Sansa had been. Whereas if she removed him then her granddaughter might still get the crown but without all of the danger. So is that a case where the end justifies the means? I don’t know. That’s what I want the reader or viewer to wrestle with, and to debate.

Comment: I knew that Olena was involved and she and little finger also pinned it on Sansa by plotting her escape at the same time. my question is regarding Tywin's Role in this

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're asking for opinions. Martin has not confirmed who **actually** did it but he's clearly stated that it's his intention that Olenna was resposible. There is no indication that Tywin would have sanctioned it or been involved.

Comment: I think you're right

Comment: @Paulie_D Per season 7 I think you can update this :)